# Jordan normal form of $A\in Mat(4,4,\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Calculate the jordan normal form of the following matrix:$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & -2\\ 1 & 0 & 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$.

The characteristic polynomial is $$\chi_A(x)=(x^2-4x+4)(x^2-2x+1)$$ with eigenvalues $x_1=2,\ x_2=1$ with multiplicity of $2$.

Do I have to calculate:$$ker((A-x_iI)^2)$$ or $$ker(A^2-4A+4I)$$

Comment: In fact, it's enough to calculate $\dim \ker (A - x_i I)$.  In each case, we *know* that $\dim \ker (A - x_i I)^2 = 2$.

Comment: From a deleted answer: a [link](http://www.karlahernandez.com/randomscience/all-posts/resources/some-things-regarding-jordan-canonical-forms/) with a general "how to" for Jordan normal form

Comment: @KarlaH. your input was useful as a comment, but it failed to address the particular question and so was insufficient as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that 
$$
\dim \ker (A - I) = \dim \ker (A - 2I) = 1
$$
As such, $A$ has Jordan canonical form
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1\\&1\\&&2&1\\&&&2
}
$$

Comment: $$dim(ker(A-I))=dim(<(0,0,1,1)^T>)=1, dim(ker(A-2I))=dim(<(1,1,1,1)^T>)=1$$

Comment: Your first calculation is correct, your second is not.

Comment: $ker(A-2I)=\pmatrix{
1&-1\\1&-1\\&1&1&-2\\1&&2&-3
}$ and $ker(A-2I)\cdot (k,k,k,k)=0, k\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @serge oh, you're right! I miscalculated.  Well done.

Comment: What does it mean that $dim(ker(A-x_iI))=1$ to the JCF? What will happen if its zero for example?

Comment: It means that we only have one (linearly independent eigenvalue) for each $x_i$.  In other words, we have *exactly one Jordan block* for each $x_i$.  $\dim \ker (A - x_i I)$ is in general the number of Jordan blocks associated with $x_i$.